# my admob banner shows in top

Tags: objective-c, ios, admob

I have a admob banner in my app and I've implemented it with the documentation AdMob provided, the only thing wrong with it is that it does not show at the bottom of the screen but in the top instead. Now I've been looking for a long time But I can't find how to change it and I can't find anyone one the net solving this problem.

Someone knows how to fix this?

Thanks

EDIT

```
// Create a view of the standard size at the bottom of the screen.
// Available AdSize constants are explained in GADAdSize.h.
bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner];

// Specify the ad's "unit identifier." This is your AdMob Publisher ID.
bannerView_.adUnitID = @"MYID";    
// Let the runtime know which UIViewController to restore after taking
// the user wherever the ad goes and add it to the view hierarchy.
bannerView_.rootViewController = self;
[self.view addSubview:bannerView_];

// Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad.
[bannerView_ loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
```

been looking for numbers on all the admob scripts but Can't find any to edit..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Have you tried changing the frame of the view (GADBannerView I think?) to position it at the bottom instead of the top?

Here's an example (you should replace the placeholders with the correct attributes:
bannerView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 460 - `bannerheight`, `bannerwidth`, `bannerheight`);

---

**edit:**

*All you need to do is replace this:*

```
bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner];
```

*With all of this:*

```
// Initialize the banner at the bottom of the screen.
CGPoint origin = CGPointMake(0.0,
                               self.view.frame.size.height -
                               CGSizeFromGADAdSize(kGADAdSizeBanner).height);

// Use predefined GADAdSize constants to define the GADBannerView.
bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner
                                                  origin:origin];
```

Comment: is this what I'm looking for? how would I modify it? // Get a custom GADAdSize that spans the full width of the application in
// portrait orientation with the height provided.
GADAdSize GADAdSizeFullWidthPortraitWithHeight(CGFloat height);

// Get a custom GADAdSize that spans the full width of the application in
// landscape orientation with the height provided.
GADAdSize GADAdSizeFullWidthLandscapeWithHeight(CGFloat height);

Comment: `initWithAdSize` defaults the ad to the top of the screen (origin is 0.0, 0,0). You're never actually telling it to be at the bottom. There is another init function that allows you to define the origin. See my edit for your answer.

Comment: That is awesome it works great only 1 thing, In my app I do not show the iPhone status bar and I think that's the reason for the add not to show at the absolute bottom its like the size of the status bar up if you know what I mean, been trying to modify that 0,0 but doesn't work any tip for this aswel :P ?

Comment: 0.0 is the x positioning, so that won't help. You just need to add 20p to the height of your view. Copy my edited code.

Comment: Can you please explain why you added 20 pixels?

Answer (score 2):

```
CGFloat height = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;

bannerView_=[[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:(kGADAdSizeBanner) origin:CGPointMake(0,height-kGADAdSizeBanner.size.height)];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CGPoint origin = CGPointMake(0.0,bannerHeight);
self.addBanner = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait
                                             origin:origin];
```

this for all iphones and iPads