# Display admob ads with a custom size in iPhone

Tags: iphone, admob

Can I display admob ads with a custom size in iphone, such as 280x50, not 320x50 typically ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Custom Ad Size

In addition to the standard AdMob ad units, DFP allows you to serve any sized ad unit into an application. Note that the ad size (width, height) defined for an ad request should match the dimensions of the ad view displayed on the application (i.e. DFPBannerView).

**Example:**

```
// Define custom GADAdSize of 280x30 for DFPBannerView
GADAdSize customAdSize = GADAdSizeFromCGSize(280, 30);
// Don't use autorelease if you are using ARC in your project
self.adBanner = [[[DFPBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:customAdSize] autorelease];
```

Note: DFP does not currently support Smart Banners.

### Multiple Ad Sizes

DFP allows you to specify multiple ad sizes which may be eligible to serve into a DFPBannerView. There are three steps needed in order to use this feature:

In the DFP UI, create a line item targeting the same ad unit that is associated with different size creatives.
In your application, set the validAdSizes property on DFPBannerView:

```
// Define an optional array of GADAdSize to specify all valid sizes that are appropriate
// for this slot. Never create your own GADAdSize directly. Use one of the
// predefined standard ad sizes (such as kGADAdSizeBanner), or create one using
// the GADAdSizeFromCGSize method.
//
// Note: Ensure that the allocated DFPBannerView is defined with an ad size. Also note
// that all desired sizes should be included in the validAdSizes array.  

GADAdSize size1 = GADAdSizeFromCGSize(CGSizeMake(120, 20));
GADAdSize size2 = GADAdSizeFromCGSize(CGSizeMake(250, 250));
GADAdSize size3 = GADAdSizeFromCGSize(CGSizeMake(320, 50));
NSMutableArray *validSizes = [NSMutableArray array];
[validSizes addObject:[NSValue valueWithBytes:&size1 objCType:@encode(GADAdSize)]];
[validSizes addObject:[NSValue valueWithBytes:&size2 objCType:@encode(GADAdSize)]];
[validSizes addObject:[NSValue valueWithBytes:&size3 objCType:@encode(GADAdSize)]];
bannerView_.validAdSizes = validSizes;
```

Implement the GADAdSizeDelegate method to detect an ad size change.

```
@protocol GADAdSizeDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)adView:(GADBannerView *)view willChangeAdSizeTo:(GADAdSize)size;
@end
```

Remember to set the delegate using the setAdSizeDelegate: before making the request for an ad.

```
[bannerView_ setAdSizeDelegate:self];
```

Be sure to set the GADBannerView's adSizeDelegate property to nil before releasing the view:

```
- (void)dealloc {
 bannerView_.adSizeDelegate = nil;

 // Don't release the bannerView_ if you are using ARC in your project
 [bannerView_ release];
 [super dealloc];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same problem. In the past it as possible to change the frame of the ad's UIView object, but now it causes an immediate `didFailToReceiveAdWithError:`.

Also, calling `DFPBannerView setSize:` with a non standard size has no effect.

My solution was to simply set the scaling of the `DFPBannerView`:

```
    GADBannerView *retVal = [self.dfpAd];
    float scaleX = w / (retVal.adSize.size.width - 0.5f);
    float scaleY = h / (retVal.adSize.size.height - 0.5f);
    float scaleFactor = MAX(scaleX, scaleY);

    retVal.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale( scaleFactor, scaleFactor);

    //        [((DFPBannerView *) retVal) resize:GADAdSizeFromCGSize(CGSizeMake(w, h))]; // Of course not working....

    // iPhone 6 and above fix. Won't rescale correctly if you don't layout. Do this after addSubView!
    //        [retVal setNeedsLayout];
    //        [retVal layoutIfNeeded];
```

Also - please mind the iPhone 6 and above fix.

Comment: I do the same but had to put banner inside banner container (UIView) and I am doing transform with this container. For me works with ios9

Answer (score 2):

**In Swift 4 to display adMob with custom frame (Tested code in simulator)**

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController, GADBannerViewDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("Google Mobile Ads SDK version: \(GADRequest.sdkVersion())")

        let bannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeMediumRectangle)

        //OR You can give custom frame
        //let bannerView = GADBannerView.init(frame:CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 250))

        bannerView.adUnitID = "YOUR adUnitID"
        bannerView.rootViewController = self
        bannerView.delegate = self
        //bannerView.adSize = kGADAdSizeMediumRectangle

        let request = GADRequest()
        request.testDevices = [kGADSimulatorID];

        bannerView.load(request)
        self.view.addSubview(bannerView)
    }

    //MARK : GADBannerView Delegates
    /// Tells the delegate an ad request loaded an ad.
    func adViewDidReceiveAd(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
        print("adViewDidReceiveAd")
    }

    /// Tells the delegate an ad request failed.
    func adView(_ bannerView: GADBannerView,
                didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: GADRequestError) {
        print("adView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    /// Tells the delegate that a full-screen view will be presented in response
    /// to the user clicking on an ad.
    func adViewWillPresentScreen(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
        print("adViewWillPresentScreen")
    }

    /// Tells the delegate that the full-screen view will be dismissed.
    func adViewWillDismissScreen(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
        print("adViewWillDismissScreen")
    }

    /// Tells the delegate that the full-screen view has been dismissed.
    func adViewDidDismissScreen(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
        print("adViewDidDismissScreen")
    }

    /// Tells the delegate that a user click will open another app (such as
    /// the App Store), backgrounding the current app.
    func adViewWillLeaveApplication(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
        print("adViewWillLeaveApplication")
    }
}
```

**Note : in AppDelegate**

```
GADMobileAds.configure(withApplicationID: "YOUR ApplicationID")
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the iOS 5 version the `kGADAdSizeBanner` allows only specific size changes. See the code below .

```
bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,0.0, 320.0, 300.0)];
bannerView_.adUnitID = MY_BANNER_UNIT_ID;
bannerView_.rootViewController = self;
[self.view addSubview:bannerView_];
[bannerView_ loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
```

Though you can Checkout this link...
[my admob banner shows in top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11286301/my-admob-banner-shows-in-top)

Answer (score 1):

TRY MY INSTRUCTION

In YourviewController header file

```
#import "GADBannerView.h"

@interface YourviewController : UIViewController 
{
  GADBannerView *admob_view;
}
```

After In YourViewcontroller implementation file:

```
#import "MainViewController.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#define AdMob_ID @"a150349d7c43186" 

@implementation YourviewController 
{
  -(void)viewDidLoad
 {
    admob_view = [[GADBannerView alloc]
                  initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,415.0,320,60)];//in this line mention your adview size

    admob_view.adUnitID = AdMob_ID;
    admob_view.rootViewController = self;
    [self.view addSubview:admob_view];


    GADRequest *r = [[GADRequest alloc] init];
    r.testing = YES;
    [admob_view loadRequest:r];

 }

}
```

above code note this line: `admob_view = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,415.0,320,60)];`

you can use **CGRectMake(x,y,width,height)** to assign modify your admob ads view like such as your requirement below code:

```
admob_view = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,415.0,280,50)];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can see this link https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/intermediate#ios
and according to that custom size of  admob ads not possible in iphone

Answer (score 0):

> Instead of providing size by yourself, just pass the size of that view
> in which you're gonna add the GADBannerView.

For eg:-

```
    let size = GADAdSize(size: self.adView.size, flags: 1)
    let bannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: size)
    bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716"
    bannerView.rootViewController = self
    self.adView.addSubview(bannerView)


    bannerView.load(GADRequest())
```

> This is more clean and easy way. you will see the ads according to the
> container view size.

Answer (score -2):

just go to the `GADBannerView.h` file and you will find following code

```
#define GAD_SIZE_320x50     CGSizeMake(320, 50)
```

just edit `CGSizeMake(320, 50)` to `CGSizeMake(280, 50)`

Comment: While undoubtedly a simple solution this is not really recommended as the change would have to be performed every time the SDK is updated.