# Change the adsize in GADBannerView

Tags: ios, admob, landscape-portrait

I integrated the admob.My App supports both Portrait and Landscape modes.In portrait mode,it works perfectly but landscape mode not changed the adsize.In Landscape mode,the bannerview ad contains left and right space.

how to change the adsize?

Kindly help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display admob ads with a custom size in iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12793865/display-admob-ads-with-a-custom-size-in-iphone)

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for full-width ads, use the smart banner format:

```
-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInt
                               duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
  if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInt)) {
    self.adBanner.adSize = kGADAdSizeSmartBannerLandscape;
  } else {
    self.adBanner.adSize = kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait;
  }
}
```

Changing the ad size like this will automatically trigger a new request for you using the new size.

Answer (score 2):

Swift answer to compliment the obj-c one.

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation.isLandscape.boolValue {
        self.bannerView.adSize = kGADAdSizeSmartBannerLandscape;
    } else {
        self.bannerView.adSize = kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to simply scale the banner view, as everything else seems to fail:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32203739/606351

Answer (score 0):

simply set GADBannerView frame's width to self.view.frame.size.width in autroate deleagate methods.  Like this

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate 
{
   CGRect tframe = _adView.frame;
   tframe.size.width = self.view.frame.size.width;
   _adView.frame = tframe;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work anymore. Causes an immediate call to the ad server, followed by a didFailToReceiveAdWithError:

Answer (score 0):

For Landscape
Ipad and Iphone

```
[bannerView setAdSize:GADAdSizeFullWidthLandscapeWithHeight(90)];

[bannerView setAdSize:GADAdSizeFullWidthLandscapeWithHeight(50)];
```

For Portrait
Ipad and Iphone

```
[bannerView setAdSize:GADAdSizeFullWidthPortraitWithHeight(90)];

[bannerView setAdSize:GADAdSizeFullWidthPortraitWithHeight(50)];
```