# Admob display issue in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, admob

i'm working on an app in which i'm integrating admob. I have given my ad unit and App Id but the ads are not displaying. This is what i code in appdelegate,

```
 [GADMobileAds configureWithApplicationID:@"ca-app-pub-6419920332120857~7417324780"];
```

This is how i coded in VC class,

```
//Admob Banner
bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 70)];
NSLog(@"%@",bannerView_);
bannerView_.adUnitID = @"ca-app-pub-6419920332120857/8171578220";
GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
bannerView_.rootViewController = self;
[self.view addSubview:bannerView_];
[bannerView_ loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];

request.testDevices = @[ @"326e918015806f8d65a43e86f9e6e939" ];

NSLog(@"%@",request);
```

Comment: did you try to check in real device ?

Comment: in your code you may be make some minor mistakes, i am not able to test this but just replace with my code and test again

Comment: try to check solution on this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12793865/display-admob-ads-with-a-custom-size-in-iphone/50213131#50213131

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this code i made some changes in you code**

```
#import <GoogleMobileAds/GoogleMobileAds.h>

@interface ViewController ()<GADBannerViewDelegate>
{

}

@property(nonatomic, strong) GADBannerView *bannerView;

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize bannerView;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    bannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 70)];
    bannerView.adUnitID = @"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716"; //change this key
    GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
    //request.testDevices = @[ @"326e918015806f8d65a43e86f9e6e939" ];
    request.testDevices = @[ kGADSimulatorID ];
    bannerView.rootViewController = self;
    bannerView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:bannerView];
    [bannerView loadRequest:request];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/// Tells the delegate an ad request loaded an ad.
- (void)adViewDidReceiveAd:(GADBannerView *)adView {
    NSLog(@"adViewDidReceiveAd");
}

/// Tells the delegate an ad request failed.
- (void)adView:(GADBannerView *)adView
didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(GADRequestError *)error {
    NSLog(@"adView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}

/// Tells the delegate that a full-screen view will be presented in response
/// to the user clicking on an ad.
- (void)adViewWillPresentScreen:(GADBannerView *)adView {
    NSLog(@"adViewWillPresentScreen");
}

/// Tells the delegate that the full-screen view will be dismissed.
- (void)adViewWillDismissScreen:(GADBannerView *)adView {
    NSLog(@"adViewWillDismissScreen");
}

/// Tells the delegate that the full-screen view has been dismissed.
- (void)adViewDidDismissScreen:(GADBannerView *)adView {
    NSLog(@"adViewDidDismissScreen");
}

/// Tells the delegate that a user click will open another app (such as
/// the App Store), backgrounding the current app.
- (void)adViewWillLeaveApplication:(GADBannerView *)adView {
    NSLog(@"adViewWillLeaveApplication");
}
```

**Install pod for easy integration `pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'`**

Comment: I have tested it on test ads it is showing me ads fine but when i run that on my real device it does not show any ads. @Hardik Thakkar

Comment: it is just showing test ads, i want live ads on my app. @Hardik Thakkar

Comment: You need to create app for that and link app with admob account, please refer document online you will get steps for that.

Comment: Check log in real device using above delegate method it will print if some error is there in configration, put break points and check

Comment: i have created the app and place the AppID and adUnit ID of that created app on admob, but still showing me test ads. @Hardik Thakkar

Comment: You made small mistake in configration i think because i use above same code and i am not facing issue ( only i change my account AppID and AdunitID)

Comment: i have written all of my code in the question. and my AppID and AdunitID is also correct i have rechecked from the project on admob. @Hardik Thakkar

Comment: Are ads are showing to u with my id's ? @Hardik Thakkar

Comment: Let me check in device with your ad's ID

Comment: @Hamza did you check this log in delegate : adView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError: Request Error: **No ad to show.** i got this error in device with your AdUnitID (Try this adUnitID :: ca-app-pub-9705890234925635/7900036590)

Comment: @Hamza if i use this (9705890234925635/7900036590)  AdUnitID it will shows real advertisment. one more thing after create AdUnitID you need to sync this with the app in itunes.

Comment: so when i upload the app on itunes than it will show the real ads? @Hardik Thakkar

Comment: No, in admob account one option which link the ad with the app which is in iTunes, so if your app is live you can search app from that and select that app which this ad. i need to check that steps till try with AdUnitID which i provide you in above comment.

Comment: i should try with ur adunit id now? @Hardik Thakkar

Comment: yes you can try with that ca-app-pub-9705890234925635/7900036590, so you can sure that in code we don't have any issue, then we can focus on setup part from admob.

Comment: i have added ur ad unit id to the app it is showing details in console but no ad is showing on screen. @Hardik Thakkar

Comment: Is your app is on appstore or you create app on itunes connect ?

Comment: Its on appstore. @Hardik Thakkar

Comment: i use AppID of your account and AdUnit ID of my account i can see real ad in device, please check with above configuration only you need to change AdUnit ID to cross check.

Comment: Let me try, Why it is not coming with my Adunit ID? @Hardik Thakkar

Comment: In admob after you sync your AdUnit ID with your app on app store it will resolve. but first test with above AdUnit ID and check first.

Comment: On admob did you find "Have you published your app on Google Play or the App Store?" this type of text in this step you need to add your app which is on itunes. i think you skip this step. (Check video on this link : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xc__SDt7S9sUPoicQltjVL5gjwjDmZEi/view)

Comment: Yeah i got that and place their my app name which is on Appstore. @Hardik Thakkar

Comment: ok good so, now select your app from that and try again with your appid and adunitID.

Answer (score 0):

> [GADMobileAds
>   configureWithApplicationID:@"ca-app-pub-6419920332120857~7417324780"];

You need to change this code like as below

> [GADMobileAds
>   configureWithApplicationID:@"ca-app-pub-6419920332120857/7417324780"];

~ is not working from new implementation. 
you can also check on test advertise in a simulator as test device as like below

> request.testDevices = [UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor ??
>   "","Your simulator id"]

Comment: I have tested it on test ads it is showing me ads fine but when i run that on my real device it does not show any ads. @RAHUL H KAMBAD